# How to take template assignment without friend c++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++98

I write template for ::iterator and ::const_iterator. template class - base_iter
In this classes store some value. How I can use assignment between class base_iter and base_iter without friend and c++11 features?
Something like
::iterator it1 = ::const_iterator it2
To make it1._value == it2._value
and construct like

```
iterator_base<const T> & operator=(iterator_base<T> const &rhs) {
    this->p = rhs.p; // not work because p is private
};
```

Comment: `friend`, or provide getter/setter, or make the field public?

Comment: can't do this. I have some rules about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot overload `operator=` outside class definition. If this code is inside a class definition for `iterator_base<T>` then it will also have access to `iterator_base<T>::p`.